# Please tell where this default/Check constraint is incorrect

Tags: sql, database, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
CREATE TABLE Article
(
    ArCode Char(5) CONSTRAINT Ar_code_pk PRIMARY KEY,
    ArName Varchar2(30) CONSTRAINT Ar_Name_nn NOT NULL,
    Rate Number(8,2),
    Quantity Number(4) DEFAULT 0 CHECK(Quantity >= 0),
    Class Char(1) CONSTRAINT cls_ck CHECK(Class IN ('A', 'B', 'C'))
)
```

Comment: Since as Littlefoot indicates, the code itself executes without error, it would really help for you to tell us *what you mean* by "incorrect".

Comment: I'm guessing this is a homework or test question, and there are facts around the data model not shared in the question above. So it's technically correct but not real world correct.

Comment: This is the question

Column Name Data Type Constraints DESCRIPTION
ArCode CHAR(5) PRIMARY KEY; Must begin with character 'A' Unique code of the article e.g. A1001, A1004
ArName VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL Article Name
Rate NUMBER(8,2)  Rate of the article. For ex. 5000.0
Quantity NUMBER(4) Greater than or equal to 0; Default Value is 0 Quantity availability of the article. For ex. 20
Class CHAR(1) Can be A, B or C Class of the article

Comment: @shubhamchaturvedi then please update your question...don't put details in as comments, makes it impossible to read/understand in context

Answer (score 1):

Nowhere, looks OK.

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE Article
  2  (
  3     ArCode     CHAR (5) CONSTRAINT Ar_code_pk PRIMARY KEY,
  4     ArName     VARCHAR2 (30) CONSTRAINT Ar_Name_nn NOT NULL,
  5     Rate       NUMBER (8, 2),
  6     Quantity   NUMBER (4) DEFAULT 0 CHECK (Quantity >= 0),
  7     Class      CHAR (1) CONSTRAINT cls_ck CHECK (Class IN ('A', 'B', 'C'))
  8  );

Table created.

SQL>
```